# Git статус сборки приложения с базой

Tags: java, база-данных, git, непрерывная-интеграция

Дали тестовое задание написать простой сервис для вывода данных из базы. Сделал с помощью Spring boot. Также нужно залить проект на гит и отобразить статус сборки (Travis CI) но как туда подвязать базу(что бы тесты крутились)? И как отдать это тестовое компании? отдать им скрипты создания базы и таблицы? или есть какие то продвинутые решения?

Comment: Продвинутые решения - это Flyway и Liqubase. Они автоматически накатывают SQL из папки или JAR на БД при старте приложения.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Список поддерживаемых Travis CI баз данных и способы их подключения смотрите в [документации](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/database-setup/).
2. Отдавать нужно в таком виде, чтобы проверяющая сторона смогла а) легко поднять ваше приложение и б) почитать код. Т.е. отдаете все исходники, плюс пишете краткую инструкцию как все поднять, либо создаете батник. Что касается БД — да, канонический вариант — это набор скриптов для поднятия/заполнения базы. Их выполнение опять же можно спрятать в батник.